# Angular: Navigate Router Does Not Work properly

Tags: angular

My angular application always sends me back to the root even when I'm already on 'bacheca'

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        /*canActivate: [AuthGuard],*/
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'bacheca',
                component: BachecaComponent
            },
            {
                path: '',
                component: TicketComponent
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

//--------------

this.router.navigate(['bacheca']); //not work
```

instead in html href="#/bacheca" work fine!

if I use it within the http subscribe works fine!!!!

out() {
        return this.http.post(GlobalService.endPoint + `/appLogout`, null);
    }

```
logout() {

    this.out()
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                //localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
                //this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
                this.router.navigate(['/bacheca']);
                //this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
            },
            error => {
                localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
                this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/bacheca']);
```

Comment: No, it not works.

I don't understand why browsing via url on the browser or using a href link works perfectly instead. what is the difference?

Comment: Try using this way: 

```constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {}```

and then using it in your method like this: 
**```this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/bacheca'))```**

Comment: Can you try it without using slash like **this.router.navigate(['bacheca']);**

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9eot.png)

In the copied image I highlighted when my component executes constructor and when ngOnInit.

and as you can see from the code there is practically nothing but something call navigation to '/':

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-bacheca',
    templateUrl: './bacheca.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bacheca.component.sass']
})
export class BachecaComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log('BachecaComponent Const');
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('BachecaComponent');
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved.
in my html, the element that called the function to change page had the attribute href = "#"